# React + Spring @GetMapping with @RequestParam simple app

Tags: java, reactjs, spring

I am trying to make a simple web app, that will have 3 forms for data input, Submit button and Results form.

**Requirements:** When I enter a data in forms and push Submit button, these parameters should go to a controller and after that React should also parse data from json response that comes from the controller and show parsed data in the Results form.

I have the Spring Controller that takes 3 parameters and return json file as a response.

But I am new with React. I've tried to use different approaches, but stuck with what way exactly I need to do it in this case. So need a help to create a simple React part.

Controller part:

```
@GetMapping("/current/city")
    public JSONObject getCurrentPollutionDataByCityStateCountry(
            @RequestParam(value = "city") String city,
            @RequestParam(value = "state") String state,
            @RequestParam(value = "country") String country
    ) {
        try {
            return pollutionService.getCurrentPollutionDataByCityStateCountry(city, state, country);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new JSONObject();
    }
```

Response example:

```
{"date":"Tue Dec 06 22:13:32 CET 2022","no2":"48.67","pm10":"9.51","pm2_5":"5.85"}
```

**UPDATE**
Here is my App.js part:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './App.css'

import axios from 'axios'

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            city: 'New York',
            province: 'New York',
            country: 'US',
            responseData: ''
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/pollution/current/city?' +
            'city=' + this.state.city +
            '&state='+ this.state.province +
            '&country=' + this.state.country)
            //not sure about setState here and what is going after that
            .then(response => this.setState({responseData: response.data.date})) 
        
        //need to take all fields from response
        //just alert message with returned response for now
        alert('Response: ' + this.state.responseData);
        
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    City:
                    <input name="city" type="text" value={this.state.city} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                </label>
                <br/>
                <label>
                    State:
                    <input name="state" type="text" value={this.state.province} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                </label>
                <br/>
                <label>
                    Country:
                    <input name="country" type="text" value={this.state.country} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </label>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default App
```

But I am not sure about my approach in general and particularly about parts where I left comments in App.js.

To be more precise with questions:

1. Should this approach work for my case or I need to implement some different logic?
2. If yes, how I can get all fields from response? I mean not only the first one (date) but no2, pm10, pm2_5 also. For now this logic can return only a first value from json.
3. How I can set these fields to show them in pop-up window (alert) or if question 2 will be solved, this thing also will be good in current form?

Comment: I would recommend you to go through a few tutorials first about react and after going through them you actually implement **something** to try it out. The way your question is right now can be considered off-topic as you don't have a problem you are seeking recommendations about what to do in a specific language which leads to opinionated answers, therefore off-topic here. If you were able to learn how to build your server application I'm sure you can do the same with the front end part of it :)

Comment: You don't have a technical question here, you are just explaining that you don't know how to create a simple React App to call your spring app.
I'd suggest you to understand the basis of a React app in baby steps:

1 - How to create a simple form? (no css worries)
2 - How to trigger a HTTP call in a button click ?  (hard coded params)
3 - Change the HTTP call to use the form state.
4 - Update the state with the HTTP result...

Comment: @JorgeCampos, thank you for you response! Yes, I've passed few tutorials and I have code that works for different forms/options. But I am not sure that I use these options together for my particular case correctly. I've updated the question with what I have. But it doesn't work for me when I start work with several parameters in response. Could you take a look what I've missed or did wrong?

Comment: @FabioMiranda thank you for you response! Yes, you are right, it was better to add what I have even if I am not sure that I am going the right way, my apologies. I've updated the question with what I have. But it doesn't work for me when I start work with several parameters in response. Actually, I did it step by step as you described. But stuck at this point. Could you take a look what I've missed or did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I think you need to solve is to set the data not data.date
use this:

```
this.setState({responseData: response.data}))
```

then access your data fields using

```
responseData.date
```

you can replace date with any other field.

do the same for alerts.

your code is working fine, furthermore, you can learn to use functional component instead of class, its much easier.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried to do it, but I don't see any alert window after pushing Submit button. Actually, I just recognized an issue - after pushing Submit button, I see the next link http://localhost:3000/?city=New+York&state=New+York&country=US, but there should be */pollution/current/city*?city=New+York&state=New+York&country=US . And I see the same result if I just leave axios.get(this.state.city + this.state.province + this.state.country). So it seems that strings in axios.get don't take a part in process. Why it can happens?

Comment: I am not sure that is the reason why I don't see the alert window, but anyway there is some issue with link generation/routing.

Comment: but you said everything is working fine! you just doesn't know which approach to take.

Comment: as in your code you are setting the returned data to date, so, you can't access other fields if you did this. you need to set the responseData to data.